# Render HTML as Firefox would, without running Firefox

Tags: image, firefox, shell

What command-line utility renders HTML as Firefox would, creating a 
static image, without actually running Firefox and xwd (or ScreenGrab, 
etc)?

Since all of Firefox's rendering libraries are open source, I'm 
assuming someone's written something like this? It would be very 
useful.

I realize static images can't have Flash animation (animated GIF/PNG 
notwithstanding), JavaScript, etc, so I'm just looking for something 
that renders plain HTML.

Comment: Are you just looking to open a page and disable the javascript?  Firefox is basically an HTML rendering engine.  I am not certian what you are actually looking for.  Perhaps you could rephrase with your goal and requirements.

Comment: If you're okay with using a third-party, you could try http://www.browsershots.org

Comment: @Chad I want to do all this "automatically". For example, cron a job that takes a rendered snapshot of my website every day at 2am. I don't think there's an option to Firefox that says "run yourself, visit this page, take a screen shot of what you've rendered, and shut yourself down". If there is, that's what I want.

@Spudley I'm trying to replicate browsershots.org locally... I don't want to rely on a third party.

Comment: There is nothing that will do what you want easily with out using a third party application unless you can script it to do just what you said open firefox, on render complete take screen shot, save screenshot, close ff.

Comment: OK, it turns out html2ps is the first step here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) is worth a try, although it does not seem to use the css style sheets. This is a serious limitation.

On Debian/Ubuntu, it is provided as a package, so the classical `sudo apt-get install html2ps` will be fine.

(I know this has been given in the comments, but for the future reader, I thought it might be easier to find as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small script which simply runs firefox using the command line options does a screen-shot, then closes firefox. Should only be about 3 lines of code to get started.

`firefox -url http://mysite.com/homepage.php`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options